# How to print unsigned char[] as HEX in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, printf, unsigned-char

I would like to print the following hashed data. How should I do it?

```
unsigned char hashedChars[32];
SHA256((const unsigned char*)data.c_str(),
       data.length(), 
       hashedChars);
printf("hashedChars: %X\n", hashedChars);  // doesn't seem to work??
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The hex format specifier is expecting a single integer value but you're providing instead an array of `char`.  What you need to do is print out the `char` values individually as hex values.

```
printf("hashedChars: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  printf("%x", hashedChars[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Since you are using C++ though you should consider using `cout` instead of `printf` (it's more idiomatic for C++.

```
cout << "hashedChars: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  cout << hex << hashedChars[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: @vidit the user gave the questions in terms of `printf` so I decided to answer that way. They clearly have a bit of confusion as to how `printf` works, and I wanted to clear that up

Comment: Ok Sir. I was just thinking because he tagged C++

Comment: `printf` is valid C++ too! There are times when I use it instead of streams. It has its place.

Comment: @vidit i went ahead and added the C++ version as well for completeness

Comment: @aardvarkk- Yes it is, but I thought we should prefer C++ features compared to the ones carried from C

Comment: It's more "would" than "should", otherwise it's like saying things like eg.: `sin` and `isspace` should not be used.

Comment: @JaredPar So.. the `printf` actually worked for me, but `cout` didn't work for me. I am using `xCode` and "hashedChars: " got printed, but not the rest.

Comment: @Louis_PIG i tried this locally and it's working on my machine. I'm not familiar enough with xCode to diagnose any problems easily. Have you tried printing without the `hex` to see what it does?

Comment: You'll want to ensure that 2 digits are output for each `char`, otherwise you'll be missing some zeros from the output. For the printf change the format to `%02X`, not sure how to do it for cout.

Comment: @JaredPar as indicated by @louis.luo , the `cout << hex << ...` does not work for me

Comment: FWIW, had to cast to `unsigned int`, i.e. `hex << (unsigned int)hashedChars[i]` to get it to work for me.

Comment: Does %x actually expect the argument to be of type char and not int or something else? If yes, can you point me to the part of the specification that says that?

Answer (score 4):

In C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned char buf0[] = {4, 85, 250, 206};
for (int i = 0;i < sizeof buf0 / sizeof buf0[0]; i++) {
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') 
              << std::setw(2) 
              << std::uppercase 
              << std::hex << (0xFF & buf0[i]) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the '0xFF & '.

Comment: While the `0xFF &` is needed to make it work, however, I must admit that it's not the most idiomatic for this case. The `0xFF &` is promoting the `unsigned char` to become an `int` so that it will result to the call of the proper overloaded method of `std::cout <<` which accepts an `int`. You can also do it like, `1 + buf0[i] - 1` and it still works. Or some esoteric means such as `+buf0[i]`. Or simply via the obvious casting `int(buf0[i])`. There is a need to promote the `buf0[i]` to become an `int`.

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed, after your response, I tried to go deeper into the cout functionality. It seems that the transformation is related to the shift operator not to cout. For more info, please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439616/can-you-bitwise-shift-a-bool-in-c. A shift of bool returns an int. As a matter of proof: bool b = true;      bool d = (b << 2);
    printf(d ? "1\n" : "0\n");

Comment: Your findings with regards to the `<<` behaving as a shift operator might be true. But in my example here, take note, the `<<` is not a shift-operator. In my example, the `<<` is overloaded by `std::cout`. Therefore, it is no longer a shift-operator. I promoted `buf0` to an `int` so that it will **hit** right to that `overload` which accepts an `int`. Otherwise, it will **hit** to a different overloaded method.

Comment: you are totally right! I integrated your idea of 'Anding' to my unit test and forgot about your example while commenting. You use no shifts!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you need to cast your `unsigned char` to be recognized as an integral (`int` or `unsigned int` since you work with positives values), and you need to add some zeros where the value could be printed by 1 character instead of 2 :

```
cout << "hashedChars: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') 
       << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(hashedChars[i]);
}
cout << endl;
```