# Can you bitwise shift a bool in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm using someone else's code that was written with an older compiler that mapped a special `BOOL` type to an `unsigned int`, but in my compiler it's mapped to a true `bool`. In some places in his code he uses the bitwise shift operator `<<` on the `bool` type, which I had never seen before and my compiler surprised me when it didn't complain.

Is that valid C++? Does the `bool` automatically get promoted to an `int` or `uint`?

I saw [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542/using-bitwise-operators-for-booleans-in-c), which provided some clarity on another issue, but it doesn't address the shift operators.

Comment: Without trawling through standardese, you can see how the operators work with a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: I've seen bitwise shift before and understand its use... I'd just never seen it used with a `bool` type. I know my compiler allows it, but will others? That's what I want to know.

Comment: What should a bitshift on a bool do logically?

Comment: @manni66 My concern was that a bitshift of `true << N` would simply toggle the bool `N` times on some compilers. If N=5 that would have resulted in a value of false instead of 32. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330321/1666676

Comment: Regarless of whether it's valid C++, it seems like an invalid _idea_ to call something `BOOL` if you're going to treat it like a bit array.

Comment: @jameslarge Exactly my line of thinking, though I think he's packing bool values into a bit array, which I suppose is why this might be expected behavior.

Comment: @Phlucious Then he shouldn’t be defining it to be equivalent to `bool`.

Comment: Why would you want to bitshift a bool - surely it's either true or false. Use an int instead ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From **Shift operators** [[expr.shift]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.shift#1)

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.
>   The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand

`bool` is an integral type so the code is well formed (`bool` is promoted to `int` and result is an `int`).

From [[conv.prom]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.prom#6), we show what integers the booleans get promoted to:

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and true becoming `one`

Afterwards, the shift behaves normally. (Thanks, @chris)

Comment: The value follows usual bool-int conversions. `false` is converted to 0 and vice-versa, while `true` is converted to 1 and anything but 0 is converted to `true`. At that point, it's a regular shift on an `int`, with conversions to and from `bool` before and after the shift.

Comment: @chris: Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's intended behavior. Can you update those citations to links? I don't understand the [foo.bar] syntax.

Comment: @Phlucious: I'm citing the standard document. I think there's an online draft somewhere I can point at. One sec.

Comment: @Phlucious: Updated to links.

Comment: I think it might be bettor to base the links on https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659 (C++17 minus some editorial changes) instead of http://eel.is/c++draft/ (latest standard, which is “an early draft [which is] known to be incomplet, incorrekt, and has lots of **bad** *formatt* `ing`.”)

Comment: and could `int` get demoted to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth to add some explanation on what others have pointed out: Bitwise shifting a `bool` is casted into `int`.

```
bool b = true;
bool d = b << 1;
printf("%d\n", d);
```

This code snippet prints `1` on the screen not `0`. The reasoning is that `b << 1` is casted to `int` which is `2` (binary `10`). The result is then casted to `bool`. The latter casting would be `0` if the value of the `int` is `0` and `1` otherwise. Since the value of the `int` is `2`, `d` stores `1`.

The right way of shifting a bool is to use it with a bitwise `AND` (`&`) with `true` (`1`).

```
bool d = (b << 1) & 1;
```

This `AND` operation forces the left side to be casted as a `bool`.

Comment: Converted, not cast[ed]. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The result type of shifting a bool is always int, regardless of what's on the right hand side.